# How to read time by user-inputted hours, minutes, seconds in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, bots, discord.py

So I am making a discord bot, and I thought that it will be a great idea to have a reminder command.

My idea here is:
User inputs `!reminder 1h 30m go for a walk`, and the bot will remind the user to go for a walk in 1 hour and 30 minutes.

I don't really know how to do it, and I didn't even try.
Here is my code(it used to take time just in seconds)
btw its the rewrite of discord.py

```
@bot.command(aliases=['rem'])
async def reminder(ctx, *args):
    if not args:
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Error", description="Please specify the arguments!", color=discord.Color.red())
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        return
    
    # Arguments reader goes here, it outputs time in seconds and the text
    
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Reminder set", description="The reminder \"{0}\" has been set to {1}".format(text, time), color=config.color)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    
    await asyncio.sleep(time)
    
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Reminder", description=text, color=config.color)
    await ctx.send(ctx.author.mention, embed=embed)
```

Comment: First of all you have to specify some other format of parsing, so in this format you can't specify `1m` is time or just reminder text.

Comment: makes sense, I think it could be separated by | or some other symbol

Comment: One thing, Every user must declare hour and minute or these are optional? And user can declare extra time units or not?

Comment: you can input hours|minutes|seconds. So you can do 1h 30m, you can do 1h, you can do 15m 30s, and you can do 45s(idk who will need it).